# Force HTTPS using 301 Redirect on IIS7 gets 401.1 Error

Tags: redirects, https, iis7, 401

I've got a site that is using an Execute URL in the 403.4 error page slot that calls a page named *forcessl.aspx*.  Here's the contents of the file:

> strWork = Replace(strQUERY_STRING, "http", "https")
>   strWork = Replace(strWork, "403;", "")
>   strWork = Replace(strWork, "80", "")
>   
>   strSecureURL = strWork
>   Response.Write(strSecureURL) 
>   Response.Redirect(strSecureURL)
>   Catch ex As Exception
>   End Try
>   End If
>   %>

This particular site gets a 401.1 error if `https://` is not added to the URL.  I have several other sites using the same method that work fine and this one mirrors those in all ways that I can tell  (folder permissions, etc). This new site is just a subdomain of the same domain that the other sites are using. The main domain has a wildcard SSL cert.

From Microsoft's documentation, here is the meaning of the errors:

#### 403.4

> HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden: SSL Is Required To View This Resource

#### 401.1

> HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Comment: You could probably easily fix this with a rewrite rule to redirect error pages to https.  I think that is what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd never heard of 403.4 or 401.1 errors.  The decimal point on them seems to be a Microsoft invention for keeping different reasons for those errors straight.   I've added information about the errors to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to this problem.

When setting up the site I had done everything but put the site in the bindings for the domain. I hadn't added the subdomain.mysite.com to the bindings for port 80.

I had forgotten this because since I was forcing everything through port 443 with a rewrite, I didn't think I needed to add it. In digging around for the solution I saw that all the other subdomains were in the bindings and this one wasn't.

A simple little thing caused 6 months of frustration. What was weird is that it worked for some people, but not for others if you tried to access it through HTTPS.

Always learning.